# Nested select query with stored procedure as sub query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use select statement to select data from the result returned by a stored procedure.

The stored procedure `PPS_WIP_Analyzer` returns a few columns, one of the columns is called status. I want to select the status column from the output of the stored procedure.

So tried below code, but it says syntax error

```
select `status` from (call PPS_WIP_Analyzer('125'))
```

Error:

> error 1064. you have an error in your sql syntax

Does anyone know what the correct way of achieving this is?

Comment: you can use the `out` type in a procedure and that out param will have the the value.

Comment: It's not a good way to use select statement in procedure. Use OUT type parameter to get output from variable. If you still want to use procedure then create a temporary table for your select query in PPS_WIP_Analyzer & create another procedure which will return status from your temporary table.